# Does FreeMagma with identity (unital magma) form list structure?

Tags: list, haskell, math, algebraic-data-types, monoids

It's sort of famous that FreeMonoids form Lists.

It seems to me that FreeMagma with identity (unital magma) also form list structure.

Am I correct?

Any additional instruction is most grateful.

Comment: By 'monoids form lists' do you mean that lists are an example of a monoid? Remember that not all monoids are lists.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's FreeMagma and FreeMonoid. Not all Monoids as you say. Thanks.

Comment: In Haskell, where infinite structures are common and useful, I think the free monoid is not lists. See also [FMList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist-0.9.2/docs/Data-FMList.html), a monoid that includes exotic objects not representable by lists, and [this article about the same technique](http://comonad.com/reader/2015/free-monoids-in-haskell/) (I can't remember which came first).

Comment: A monoid in definition does not include exotic objects. Lists may not be FreeMonoid in Hakell, but FreeMonoid is List. Keep reading on https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+monoid and http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/10/strings-lists-and-sequences-as-a-monoid/ etc.

Answer (score 4):

A free magma is made of trees, and an identity element can be added as an afterthought.

```
data FreeMagma a
  = Leaf a  -- generators
  | Node (FreeMagma a) (FreeMagma a)

-- free magma with identity
data FreeMagmaId a = Id | FreeMagma (FreeMagma a)

empty :: FreeMagmaId a
empty = Id

(<+>) :: FreeMagmaId a -> FreeMagmaId a -> FreeMagmaId a
Id <+> b = b
a <+> Id = a
FreeMagma a <+> FreeMagma b = FreeMagma (Node a b)
```

Comment: Right. It might be worthwhile to also explain briefly what this has to do with associativity.